# Area between $y=2+|x-1|$ and $y=-\frac{1}{5}x+7$

Tags: definite-integrals, modules, area

Question 17, page 448, from Anton 8th. The question asks for the area, and the answer is 24.

Now, I did draw the graph, found the points where both functions touch each other by $f(x) = g(x)$:

(-5,8) and (5,6);

I'm having problems solving the integration. I've tried so many times to solve it, but it comes to the same integral:

$$\int_{-5}^{5}-\frac{1}{5}x+7-2+|x-1|  $$ then:
$$\int_{-5}^{5}-\frac{1}{5}x+5+|x-1|  $$

$$ -\frac{x^2}{10} + 5x + |\frac{x^2}{2}-x| $$

Replacing values: 5:

$$ -\frac{5^2}{10}+5.5+\frac{5^2}{2}-5 = \color{blue}{-\frac{25}{10}+25+\frac{25}{2}-5 = 30} $$

For -5:

$$ -\frac{(-5)^2}{10}+5.(-5)-\frac{(-5)^2}{2}+(-5) = \color{blue}{-\frac{25}{10}-25-\frac{25}{2}-5} = -45 $$

then the difference between these:

$$ 30 - (-45) = 75$$

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, since the $|\frac{x^2}{2}-x|$ need to behave different on each value, for +5 = $\color{blue}{\frac{5^2}{2}-5}$ and for -5 = $\color{red}{-\frac{(-5)^2}{2}+(-5)}$

I searched by a integration calculator and found this: [integral-calculator.com](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%28-1%2F5%2Ax%2B7%29-%282%2Babs%28x-1%29%29&ubound=5&lbound=-5), but I've never seen anything like $$\frac{-(x+1).|x-1|}{2}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Updating with graph picture:

[image]

Comment: I haven't looked your work but as a general tip, I find these kinds of problems much easier if you draw a picture (so that you know what the proper bounds of integration are).

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I've put a image from WinPlot, as I stated, the points are correct so the bounds are -5 and 5. I'm having trouble to solve the integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the case that:
$$
\int |g(x)| \, dx = \left|\int g(x) \, dx\right|
$$
Instead, to get rid of the absolute values, we use the fact that:
$$
|x - 1| = \begin{cases}
x - 1 &\text{if } x \geq 1 \\
1 - x &\text{if } x < 1
\end{cases}
$$
We thus split the integral into two separate ones:
$$
\int_{-5}^1 [(\tfrac{-1}{5}x + 7) - (2 + (1 - x))] \, dx
+ \int_{1}^5 [(\tfrac{-1}{5}x + 7) - (2 + (x - 1))] \, dx
$$

Comment: Well, that was an adventure! Finally! Thank you so much. I was considering the absolute values as $x >= 0$ and $x < 0$. That was confusing everything.